# How do I insert into table primary keys from two other tables making every combination?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use MS SQL Server and I have 3 tables, A, B and C. Both A and B have column called Id. I would like to insert into C those values making every combination, so lets say table A has data:

```
Id
1
2
3
```

Table B has data:

```
Id
4
5
```

And I am trying to achive that table C has data:

```
Id | A_Id| B_Id
1  |1    | 4
2  |1    | 5
3  |2    | 4
4  |2    | 5
5  |3    | 4
6  |3    | 5
```

I will greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `cross join` :

```
select *
from tablea a cross join
     tableb b
order by a.id;
```

So, you can use `insert` statement :

```
insert into tablec (A_Id, B_Id)
     select *
     from tablea a cross join
          tableb b
     order by a.id;
```